# Display of up/down buttons in table row reordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vaDkF/828/
(without the top and bottom option) to create a reordering table.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".up,.down").click(function(){
        var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
        if ($(this).is(".up")) {
            row.insertBefore(row.prev());
        } else  {
            row.insertAfter(row.next());
        } 
       
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to know if it is possible to have the up button disappear (display none) if it is the first row in the table, and the down button disappear if it is the last row in the table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CSS for this, with `first-child` and `last-child` selectors:

```
tr:first-child .up, tr:last-child .down {
  display:none;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".up,.down").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {
      row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    } else {
      row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
tr:first-child .up,
tr:last-child .down {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
      <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
      <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
      <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
      <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Five</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
      <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaDkF/1681/)

Comment: Well that was way simpler than I was trying to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: :P @JessicaC glad to help U